# How to get UserContactLists from constant contact using c#

Tags: c#

I am going to use Constant contact for email marketing. I am not getting how to get userContactList which are all there in my constant contact account.If anyone have any idea please help me.
Thanks in advance

Comment: http://developer.constantcontact.com/

Comment: How about that : http://developer.constantcontact.com/docs/contact-list-api/contactlist-collection.html

Comment: From that site i did not get full information...i need some sample code how to achieve the same thing in c#

Comment: First, use WebClient.DownloadString and put the URL from that documentation website in it. Use the proper parameter like api_key and modified_date. The response is in JSON format and you should parse it.

Comment: my problem is im unable to call GetUserContactListCollection Method from asp.net project. if im able to call this method then i can get the list

Comment: IList<ContactList> lists = Utility.GetUserContactListCollection(_AuthenticationData, out nextChunkId); but it is showing Utility does not exist in the current context so for that i need to include ConstantContactUtility dll..rom where i can get this dll

Answer (score 0):

Here is some code I wrote a while ago that returns the user list ID based on the name of an existing user list. its all C# and uses RESTSharp library which you can install inside your VS project using Nuget.

```
            public static string GetContactListIDByListName(string listname)
            {

                feedData = string.Empty;

                id = string.Empty;
                name = string.Empty;
                status = string.Empty;
                modified_date = string.Empty;
                created_date = string.Empty;
                contact_count = 0;


                Stream stream = null;
                StreamReader streamReader = null;

                var client = new RestClient(ccURL);
                var request = new RestRequest("/v2/lists?modified_since=[DATE]&api_key=[API-KEY]", Method.GET);
                request.AddHeader("Authorization", "Bearer [ACCESS-TOKEN]");
                request.AddHeader("X-Originating-Ip", "[SERVER-IP]");
                request.AddHeader("Accept", "application/json");

                IRestResponse response = client.Execute(request);
                feedData = response.Content;

                // DESERIALIZE Mashery JSON Response

                byte[] byteArray = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(feedData);
                MemoryStream myStream = new MemoryStream(byteArray);
                DataContractJsonSerializer serializer = new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(Mashery.GetAllListsDef[]));
                object result = serializer.ReadObject(myStream);
                Mashery.GetAllListsDef[] jsonObj = result as Mashery.GetAllListsDef[];


                foreach (Mashery.GetAllListsDef myResult in jsonObj)
                {
                    if (myResult.name.ToUpper().Equals(listname.ToUpper()))
                    {
                        return myResult.id.ToString();
                    }
                }

                return "";

            }

            // JSON Definition For [GET All Lists] End Point Method
            [Serializable, XmlRoot("GetAllListsDef"), DataContract(Name = "GetAllListsDef")]
            public class GetAllListsDef
            {
                [XmlElement("id"), DataMember(Name = "id")]
                public string id { get; set; }

                [XmlElement("name"), DataMember(Name = "name")]
                public string name { get; set; }

                [XmlElement("status"), DataMember(Name = "status")]
                public string status { get; set; }

                [XmlElement("created_date"), DataMember(Name = "created_date")]
                public string created_date { get; set; }

                [XmlElement("modified_date"), DataMember(Name = "modified_date")]
                public string modified_date { get; set; }

                [XmlElement("contact_count"), DataMember(Name = "contact_count")]
                public string contact_count { get; set; }

            }
```